# How to test if a WBBAckup policy Exists

Tags: powershell

I am working on a Windows Server PS script (Server 2016-2022) and working on a specific function with the aim of checking for any Backup policies leftover on the OS and deleting them before I go any further - the aim being to make sure I don't have a policy that conflicts with the backup job I am creating

When I manually execute the command : Remove-WBPolicy -All -Force I get the error;

> `Remove-WBPolicy : You have not set a policy to be used for scheduled backups. Use Set-WBPolicy to specify a policy to be used for scheduled backups.
> At C:\Scripts\WBackup.ps1:117 char:9
> Remove-WBPolicy -All -Force
>
> - ```
>       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   ```
>
> CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Remove-WBPolicy], InvalidOperationException
> FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.Windows.ServerBackup.Commands.RemoveWBPolicy`

When I try Get-WBPolicy it returns nothing, so I put this test together

```
$str_PolicyCheck = Get-WBPolicy

# Display the output to screen to confirm nothing is returned ++ while DEV only ++
Write-Host "$str_PolicyCheck"
    If($str_PolicyCheck="") {
        Write-Host "No Policy"
        } ELSE {
        Write-Host "Policy Exists"
        }
```

The line If($str_PolicyCheck="") always evaluates it as one does exist so something is being returned.  How do I address this

To query the OS for the presence of a Policy, then evaluate if one exists to decide the next course of action